# Нужно ли тире в зависимости от смысла?

Tags: тире

Есть предложение "удовольствие (—) для дураков" и два смысла:

1. В контексте определено действие, на которое ссылается "удовольствие". То есть получается сокращение от "[конкретно это] удовольствие для дураков".
2. Всё удовольствие на самом деле для дураков. Если ты не дурак, оно недоступно.

Мне интуитивно кажется, что в первом варианте тире не нужно, а вот насчёт второго я не уверен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы правы, что в первом не нужно.

*Такое удовольствие для дураков.* || Тире не нужно, но возможно (если есть обобщение).

Но при общем факте (второй вариант), который затрагивает "всё", тире желательно.

Автору стоит ориентироваться по паузе (при тире она есть).

Тут больше смысл не о доступности удовольствия (чьё оно), а о том, что лишь дураки таким занимаются.

Продвинутая информация: при тире на слово "*удовольствие*" падает логическое ударение.